# how to use div modal with ng-repeat

Tags: html, angularjs

I want to pass loop index to the function Createprofile(). I want to do this using angular controller.

*HTML*

```
<li ng-repeat = "proteam in proteams | filter:filtText | filter:filtText1" ng-init="counter">
<p>{{proteam.description}}</p>
    <div class="modal fade" id="collaborateForm" role="dialog" hidden="true" style="overflow: auto;">
         <div class="modal-dialog">
         <!-- Modal content-->
         <div class="modal-content fade in">
              <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                      <h4 class="modal-title">COLLABORATION FORM</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body" >
         <!-- Collaborate FORM -->
                   <form  ng-submit="createProfile(counter)" onkeypress="return event.keyCode != 13;">
                        <label>Enter team Name:</label>
                               <input type="text" class="form-control" id="teamName" required="required">
                                     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" dismiss="modal" onClick="turnDivOff()">Collaborate</button>
                   </form>
               </div>
              </div>
              </div>
              </div>                                                
                        </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use track by in ng-repeat

```
<li ng-repeat = "proteam in proteams | filter:filtText | filter:filtText1 track by $index" ng-init="counter">
```

then you can use it inside the ng-repeat

```
<form  ng-submit="createProfile($index)"
```

Comment: This is the error when i use track by

 `code`

angular.js:12722Error: [filter:notarray] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.9/filter/notarray?p0=0
    at Error (native)
    at http://localhost:8080/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:6:416

Comment: oh sorry, the track by $index should be in the last. try that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this as

```
<form  ng-submit="createProfile($index)" onkeypress="return event.keyCode != 13;">
```

`ng-repeat` expected an array so it have an  index associated with it

Comment: This is not working, as $index is unable to keep track.

Answer (score 0):

> Check the below code. On every click the index of the form is alerted.

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
           .controller('myCtrl',function($scope) {
  $scope.createProfile = function(html) {
    alert(html);
  }
$scope.proteams =[{'description':'stack'}, {'description':'overflow'}]
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
<ul>
<li ng-repeat = "proteam in proteams" ng-init="counter">
<p>{{proteam.description}}</p>
    <div class="modal fade" id="collaborateForm" role="dialog" style="overflow: auto;">
         <div class="modal-dialog">
         <!-- Modal content-->
         <div class="modal-content fade in">
              <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                      <h4 class="modal-title">COLLABORATION FORM</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body" >
         <!-- Collaborate FORM -->
                   <form  ng-submit="createProfile($index)" onkeypress="return event.keyCode != 13;">
                        <label>Enter team Name:</label>
                               <input type="text" class="form-control" id="teamName" required="required">
                                     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" dismiss="modal" onClick="turnDivOff()">Collaborate</button>
                   </form>
               </div>
              </div>
              </div>
              </div>                                                
                        </li></ul>
```